# Looking for an Android Keyboard Gallery?

Tags: mobile, android, input

I'm documenting some patterns for a mobile project, and I need a page that shows all the different keyboard layouts on mobile for Android specifically (Like number pad, phone number keyboard, etc.)

I've been searching endlessly and am only finding options to download keyboard apps for Android.

This is the iOS version of what I need, but I haven't been able to find something like this for Android. I don't really care if it includes the specific code on how to implement it, I just want the images.

https://recoursive.com/2018/12/07/visual_guide_uikeyboardtype/

Answer (score 0):

Best I could find was an [Android guide](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style) that talks about implementing input fields, but they don't show all of the available configurations.

In the guide, it states

> some of the values can be combined to specify the input method appearance and additional behaviors

so I'm thinking that they don't show all of the options because it's set up to be flexible for the developer.

You can also check out the [full list of available input types](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType).